# How to grant everyone in a Google Group permission to us a Google Apps Script standalone script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-groups

I have a standalone web app coded in Google Scripts.  It's permission settings at deployment are:

Execute the app as "User accessing the web app"
Who has access to the app "Everyone"

The issue is that a lot of people will be using the app, and having to constantly check g-mail to grant each user permission is a pain.  So I'd like to create a Google Group and grant the group (all members) permission to use the app.  That way they only have to join the group to gain permission, and don't have to wait for me to grant access.

Is this possible?
If so how?
If not, is there an alternative "easy way" to grant permissions to many users?

~~~~~~~~

What I've tried:
I've tried creating a Google Group, and then going to my apps script's project page, and giving the group view only permissions.  This didn't seem to work.

Expected Results:
The expected result is an easy way for many people to be granted permission to use the app, without having to wait for a verification email to be read and confirmed by me.

Actual Results:
The actual result, as of now, is that I'm going to have either manually verify each user, or attempt to write another script that constantly scans my Gmail for access request emails, and automatically grants access to them.

Comment: I don't see any feasible solution unless you distribute it as a Web App through the Chrome Web Store https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/distribute-web-app. 

Trying to "bulk" grant access on behalf of each user are in fact making your users expose to security risks.

Comment: You need to start with https://developers.google.com/apps-script/concepts/scopes and select the most appropriate way of authorising access to your app. But I'm pretty sure there is nothing special about Google Groups that will allow you use group membership.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using the following code:

```
var users = GroupsApp.getGroupByEmail.getUsers()
var stringOfUsers = users.join(",") //This turns the array of users into a 
//string 
//which is used when sharing email addresses
DriveApp.getFileByID("yourFileID").addViewers(stringOfUsers)
```

Put this inside of a function then use a trigger to set it off however much you would like.